# Get specific Data from Json string

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON data.:

```
{"title":"",
"query":"pakistan",
"for":"daily",
"method":3,
"prayer_method_name":"University Of Islamic Sciences,
 Karachi (Hanafi)",
"daylight":"0",
"timezone":"5",
"map_image":"http:\/\/maps.google.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?center=30.375321,69.345116&sensor=false&zoom=13&size=300x300",
"sealevel":"1376",
"today_weather":{"pressure":null,"temperature":null},
"link":"http:\/\/muslimsalat.com\/pakistan",
"qibla_direction":"258.33",
"latitude":"30.375321",
"longitude":"69.345116",
"address":"","city":"",
"state":"",
"postal_code":"",
"country":"Pakistan",
"country_code":"PK",
"items":[{"date_for":"2016-6-9","fajr":"3:43 am","shurooq":"5:09 am","dhuhr":"12:21 pm","asr":"5:15 pm","maghrib":"7:34 pm","isha":"9:00 pm"}],
"status_valid":1,
"status_code":1,
"status_description":"Success."}
```

I only need specifice data from the JSON, for example,

> "fajr":"3:43 am", "shurooq":"5:09 am", "dhuhr":"12:21 pm",
>   "asr":"5:15 pm", "maghrib":"7:34 pm", "isha":"9:00

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you already tried? What about that approach is troubling you?

Comment: You aren't asking a question, so we can't give you an answer... Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON serializer such as http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

Then you'd have the following model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string date_for { get; set; }
    public string fajr { get; set; }
    public string shurooq { get; set; }
    public string dhuhr { get; set; }
    public string asr { get; set; }
    public string maghrib { get; set; }
    public string isha { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContainer
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and using json.net you could retrieve the values

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemContainer>(your json);
if (data.Items.Count > 0)
{
   var fajr = data.Items[0].fajr;
   var dhuhr = data.Items[0].dhuhr; 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your JSON into an object. For that you can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Here is an example on how to parse a JSON string into a dynamic object:

```
string source = "YOUR JSON";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);
Console.WriteLine(data.fajr);
Console.WriteLine(data.shurooq);
Console.WriteLine(data.dhuhr);
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

let say your json was stored on MyData variable:

so to take the values are:

- MyData.items => return object
- MyData.items.fajr => return string
- MyData.items.shurooq => return string
- MyData.items.dhuhr => return string
- MyData.items.asr => return string
- MyData.items.maghrib => return string
- MyData.items.isha => return string

Using newtonsoft.json:

```
var shalaSchedule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(MyData);
```

so you can read the data from `shalaSchedule["items"][0]["magrib"].toString()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class which contains attribute like json keys.Then you can easily deserialize it as below.

```
class TemplateResponse
{
    public String multicast_id;
    public String success;
    public String failure;
    public String canonical_ids;
    public Result[] results;

    public class Result
    {
        public String message_id;
        public String registration_id;
        public String error;
    };
}
```

Json String:

```
"\"multicast_id\":7400896764380883211,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1351777805148960%39895cf0f9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

Then deserialize like below snippet:

```
TemplateResponse result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TemplateResponse>(json);
string status = result.success;
```